# Regular expression for range of numbers

Tags: regex

Can somebody help me with this regular expression?
Numbers that are anything from 100 to 9999. Excluding 112, 144 and the whole 900 - 999 range.

Comment: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: Regular expressions are a poor choice of tool for this problem. Better is to use a blend of regular expressions and code-behind. Use a regular expression to detect all-digits, then code-behind to do the range checking.

Answer (score 4):

This is a great opportunity to not use regular expressions at all. You are interested in the *value* of the numbers not their *textual format* so just convert the value into an integer ( if the conversion fails you have bad input ) and then perform a numerical analysis on it.

This will be easier, more readable and very probably perform better than using a regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex if regular script/language constructs don't work for you:

```
^(?!(9[0-9]{2}|112|144)$)[1-9][0-9]{2,3}$
```